# CanCan, how to test an rspec with a modeless, controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have an admin controller w/o a model

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

    # Sign In Required - Devise Check
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    # CanCan
    before_filter :current_ability

  # CanCan for Non RESTful Controllers - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers
  # We do this as there is no admin model/resouce
  authorize_resource :class => false
```

I'm unable to figure out how to write a spec for the controller. I have the following:

```
  describe 'Admin User' do

    it "should be allow admin users to view admin#index" do
      @ability_for_user_4.can :read, Admin
      get :index
      assert_template :index
    end
  end
```

**This fails with: uninitialized constant Admin**

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You need to create an `Admin` constant if you're going to reference it..

Comment: @Ryan thanks, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does your spec start with `require 'spec_helper'` ?  Most Ruby on Rails specs start with that and it will load the Rails environment into memory.

Otherwise, you need to create a mocked model so Rspec knows what an `Admin` is.